# QGIS unique IDs with fixed number of digits

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

Does anybody know if there is a way to assign unique IDs - with a distinct number of digits - within Field Calculator? Should be an Integer, so uuid is no possibility.

Comment: A mixture of $id, row_number, wordwrap with to_string and rand() ;)

Comment: Have you tried `lpad` already? Like, `lpad($rownum, 4, '0')`.

Comment: @Kazuhito - You should post your comment as an **answer** :)

Comment: Thanks @Joseph I will. Sorry heavensiabove missed your comment.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `lpad()` function which can format strings, to a fixed number of length.

Usage can be like:

`lpad('123', 4, '0')`  -------- // `0123`

`lpad($rownum, 4, '0')` ----- // `0001`

or

`lpad("id", 4, 'x')`  ----------// `xxx0`

Please note the output is string field.